# How to move downward the textView cursor?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Can someone show me how to move the textView cursor downward cause I  don't know how to do it,
Also where should I put it 
in the textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView)  or in the textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This will move coursor to the end of text:**

```
 func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            textView.selectedRange = NSRange(location: textView.text.count, length: 0)
        }
        return true
    }
```

If you want to begin text from a new line, add this, before             **return true**:

```
textView.text = textView.text + "\n"
```

If you want to skip two lines, make it "\n\n", and so on.

Comment: the cursor didn't move

Comment: @Jose Is your delegate is working? – David Davidoff just now

Comment: yeah, I Think so how can i check if my delegate works or not

Comment: @Jose in textViewDidBeginEditing, print("It works"), and see if it gets printed in your debug console

Comment: it does print it, can you help me

Comment: I want to have two lines down, how can I do that

Comment: @Jose I edited my answer, check it out. Don't forget to upvote, and select it as a correct one.

Comment: your answer is the correct one, I can't upvote right now because it doesn't let me but since the answer is correct I put it a green check mark

Comment: Hi it works but their a bug that I want to fix, it is that if the user taps at the top it will move to the top and I want it to be locked at the second line please help, thanks in advance